# Create a list (of tuples?) from two lists of different sizes

Tags: python

I am stuck trying to perform this task and while trying I can't help thinking there will be a nicer way to code it than the way I have been trying.

I have a line of text and a keyword. I want to make a new list going down each character in each list. The keyword will just repeat itself until the end of the list. If there are any non-alpha characters the keyword letter will not be used.

For example:

```
Keyword="lemon"
Text="hi there!"
```

would result in

```
('lh', 'ei', ' ', 'mt' , 'oh', 'ne', 'lr', 'ee', '!')
```

Is there a way of telling python to keep repeating over a string in a loop, ie keep repeating over the letters of lemon?

I am new to coding so sorry if this isn't explained well or seems strange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
import itertools

def task(kw,text):
    i = itertools.cycle(kw)
    return tuple(next(i)+t if t.isalpha() else t for t in text)

print(task('lemon','hi there!'))
```

#### Output

```
('lh', 'ei', ' ', 'mt', 'oh', 'ne', 'lr', 'ee', '!')
```

[itertools.cycle](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) iterates over a sequence repeatedly (a string is a sequence of characters).  [next](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next) gets the next character from the repeating sequence.  The [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) selects the pair of next keyword letter and text character if the text character is alphabetic, else it just selects the non-alphabetic character alone.

Comment: Is there anything `itertools` can't do? No. No, there isn't.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was perfect. My attempted code was about 10 lines long and not working! I have learnt some new techniques from this.

Answer (score 3):

You've got two questions mashed into one. The first is: how do you remove non-alphanumeric chars from a string? You can do it a few ways, but regular expression substitution is a nice way.

```
import re

def removeWhitespace( s ):
    return re.sub( '\s', '', s )
```

The second part of the question is about how to keep looping through the keyword, until the text line is consumed. You can write this as:

```
def characterZip( keyword, textline ):
    res = []
    textline = removeWhitespace(textline)
    textlen = len(textline)
    for i in xrange(textlen)):
        res.append( '%s%s' % (keyword[i%len(keyword)], textline[i]) )
    return res
```

Most pythonistas will look at this and see opportunity for refactoring. The patten that this code is trying to achieve is in functional programming termed a `zip`. The quirk is that in this case you're doing something slightly non-normative with the repeating characters of the keyword, this too has an equivalent, the [cycle](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) function in the itertools module.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice, izip

def characterZip( keyword, textline ):
    textline = removeWhitespace(textline)
    textlen = len(textline)
    it = islice( izip(cycle(keyword), textline), textlen )
    return [ '%s%s' % val for val in it ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `enumerate` in that situation:

```
# remove unwanted stuff
l = [ c for c in Text if c.isalpha() ]

for n,k in enumerate(l):
   print n, (Keyword[n % len(Keyword)], Text[l])
```

that gives you:

```
0 ('l', 'h')
1 ('e', 'i')
2 ('m', 't')
3 ('o', 'h')
4 ('n', 'e')
5 ('l', 'r')
6 ('e', 'e')
```

You could use that as the basis for your manipulation.

Comment: `c.isalpha()` won't be True at the same time as `c.isspace()`.

Comment: @KirkStrauser you are right. I corrected the answer according to that suggestion.